# Is it possible to show files parent shared drive or the folder path in the document search view?

Tags: google-picker

In the Google Picker (DocsView) I only see three columns: Name, Owner and Last Modified.

Is it possible to show informations about the file current location? As for now, if I have multiple files with the same name but located different folders, I can't distinguish the file I'm looking for.